# How to remove summary in yii2 grid but keeping pager

Tags: yii2

I'm using following code which is generated by the Gii tool while creting CRUD operation

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'text:ntext',
            'status',
            'name',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "summary" key and pass it blank.

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
         'summary'=>'',
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'text:ntext',
            'status',
            'name',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [layout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$layout-detail) :

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}",
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'text:ntext',
        'status',
        'name',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```